# Ruby: Unable to reference an object of a class which was created in a different file

Tags: ruby, class, object, nameerror

I am new to Ruby and am trying to call a method of an object. I am doing this in my main file. However, The object was created in a separate file and I am getting a (NameError)

- I created a "weapons.rb" file to store 20 or so weapons with this format:
  club = Weapon.new("Club", 1, [1, 4])
- The "weapons.rb" file has
  require_relative "class_definitions" at the top (which is where I created my Weapons class)
- The method I am calling is named `damage_roll`

my main.rb file has:

```
require_relative "class_definitions"
require_relative "weapons"

puts club.damage_roll
```

And I get this error:
`<main>': undefined local variable or method 'club' for main:Object (NameError)`

However, when I do:

```
require_relative "class_definitions"
require_relative "weapons"

club = Weapon.new("Club", 1, [1, 4])

puts club.damage_roll
```

I get the ouput im looking for.

I'd rather not create twenty new Weapon types before my main file.
Is there a way to do this correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Right now we can't see what's going on in your `require`'ed segments.  Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the site's help section, and give us (small) copies of everything needed to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Right now I'm wondering whether it's a conceptual error or a misunderstanding of nomenclature. You didn't "create a new `Weapon` type", you've created an object `club` which is an instance of class `Weapon`. If you think of `Weapon` as a manufacturing plant, then `club = Weapon.new(...)` is similar to placing a custom order and accepting delivery. It's got to happen somewhere, and it makes sense to me for that to be in your program since you're the one who wants a `club`, and how many clubs or other weapons you want.

Comment: Was checking out my post history, and saw this comment. It was both a conceptual error and misunderstanding of nomenclature and I understand classes a little better now. Thanks for reaching out and providing some resources